# How to add non-standardized sql functions in Spring Boot application?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, sql-function

My app needs to be portable between Postgres, Mysql and for testing Hsqldb. I've setup Flyway to make some custom functions available on all three, that I now want to use in my SQL/HQL queries.

My current setup is using separate `Dialect`s that I switch between using `application-{profile}.yml`; which works, but the function declarations need to be duplicated among the various dialects, and it feels suboptimal.

Looking at [15.29. Non-standardized functions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-non-standard-functions) in the Hibernate documentation, it says I should be using `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration#addSqlFunction()`, which seems more portable and removes the need to extend all three dialects.

My issue is: How do I get access to the Hibernate `Configuration` class in my Spring Boot (1.3) application? There's no bean to inject by default, and no `LocalSessionFactoryBean` bean either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or at some other way to register my sql functions once?

Answer (score 3):

I have rather a hack for the issue.

Hibernate uses `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.SQLFunctionRegistry` to recognize a DB function.

Here is an example of hibernate core 4.3.10.
Internally it consists of two private fields:

```
/**
 * Defines a registry for SQLFunction instances
 *
 * @author Steve Ebersole
 */
public class SQLFunctionRegistry {
    private final Dialect dialect;
    private final Map<String, SQLFunction> userFunctions;
```

The first field represents dialect of the database.
Second contains user defined functions which can be filled by `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration#addSqlFunction()`.

Unfortunately, in my search through hibernate source code I found that configuration object created while initializing hibernate is not exposed in any way.

However, I managed to get access to SQLFunctionRegistry.

One needs to create a local autowired field of type EntityManagerFactory

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
```

and later call the following code:

```
private void registerMyDbFunctions()
{
    SQLFunctionRegistry registry = this.emFactory.unwrap(org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.class).getSqlFunctionRegistry();
    Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(SQLFunctionRegistry.class, "userFunctions");
    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
    Map<String, SQLFunction> userFunctions = (Map<String, SQLFunction>)ReflectionUtils.getField(field, registry);

    userFunctions.put("my_func", new SQLFunctionTemplate(TextType.INSTANCE, "my_func(?1, ?2)"));
}
```

Since `userFunctions` field is private and not exposed in the class, I used ReflectionUtils to get its value. It's usually empty and I just add my DB functions to it.

Since I had to get into `SqlFunctionRegistry`'s internals it's a hack, but I prefer it over creating new DB dialect and messing up with it.